# Is xxh64 hash suitable for file integrity check?

Tags: security, hash, anti-cheat

Is xxh64 hash suitable for file integrity check?
I have a game and inside this game i wan't to check some files integrity before loading ( 1mb+) to battle cheats. I know that this xxh64 is not suitable for crypto, but is it suitable for my purpose? So for instance if i have some file and i know this file exact size and xxh64 hash, how easy is to create fake file of same exact size and xxh64 hash? And even if i find collision file with same size and xxh64 hash it will be completely garbage, not suitable to use inside game ( like texture, sound, animation etc. )

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One of the main features of a cryptographically secure hash function -- probably *the* main feature -- is "preimage resistance", the property of making it computationally infeasible to find an input with a given hash. Preimage resistance is basically what you're looking for, and it is not a feature of xxHash.

More details on xxHash's weakness to preimaging are given in [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/96090/pre-image-attack-on-non-cryptographic-hash-functions). But the short answer: No, it's unsuitable. (It's also unnecessary. Modern processors are *crazy* fast at computing, say, SHA-256. There is no possible way that *that* will be the bottleneck of your gigantic data.)

Comment: i just benchmarked sha256 on piece of memory of 16KB size and a speed was 350 megabytes per second which is not crazy fast ( openssl x64 )

Comment: And how much time does it take your application to use 350 megabytes of data?

Comment: @Kracken: You haven't mentioned even rough performance requirements in your question. But the point is, it's easy to produce a bogus file of the exact same size as your target file with the same xxh64 hash, if I read that linked crypto answer correctly.